# SQL Procedure error exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the SQL Procedure below, which displays the error below when run from SQL DEveloper

```
ERROR Message: 
    ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows



PROCEDURE SP_ENABLE_CONST(P_ARCH_BATCH_ID VARCHAR) IS


TABLELIST VARCHAR2(100);
SQL_QUERY VARCHAR2(4000);
RESULT_COL INT;
RESULT_CONST_COL VARCHAR2(1000);


BEGIN
/*LOOP will return three tables designated in table_name */
FOR TEMP2_VAR_TEST IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TEST%')
 
/*each loop the table_name returned will be used in SQL_QUERY */
  LOOP

      SQL_QUERY := 'SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = :1';
     
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL_QUERY); 

/*select statement will return more than one row containing table constraints*/
**ERROR on this part since RESULT_CONST_COL cannot contain more than one row
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_QUERY INTO RESULT_CONST_COL USING TEMP2_VAR_TEST.TABLE_NAME;
      
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONSTRAINT_NAME' || RESULT_CONST_COL);
          
  END LOOP;     
  END SP_ENABLE_CONST;
END PK_ARCHIVE_PROCESS_TEST;
```

I understand that the error is caused by result_const_col which is of type VARCHAR2 but am not sure what to use to store multiple rows returned from execute immediate command. I have read about cursor and attempted to use it but still getting errors. Thanks in advance.

## Update 1

Modified my code as you have suggested but still encountered errors.

```
TYPE RESULT_CONST_COL IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
VAR_OF_RESULT_CONST RESULT_CONST_COL;

TBL_CONSTRAINTS VARCHAR2(100);
TABLELIST VARCHAR2(100);
SQL_QUERY VARCHAR2(4000);
RESULT_COL INT;


BEGIN

FOR TEMP2_VAR_TEST IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TEST%')
 
  LOOP      
      SQL_QUERY := 'SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = :1';          
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL_QUERY); 

/*ERROR line 92*/
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_QUERY USING TEMP2_VAR_TEST.TABLE_NAME
          RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO VAR_OF_RESULT_CONST;      
  
        FOR I IN 1 .. VAR_OF_RESULT_CONST.COUNT LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR_OF_RESULT_CONST(i));
        END LOOP;       
  END LOOP;
```

When I try to run the code above encountered this error

```
ORA-06547: RETURNING clause must be used with INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements
**ORA-06512: at "HSNIAPP.PK_ARCHIVE_PROCESS_TEST", line 92**
ORA-06512: at line 6
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = :1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `RESULT_CONST_COL` as collection:

```
RESULT_CONST_COL IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
```

And then use `BULK COLLECT INTO` to return multiple rows:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_QUERY BULK COLLECT INTO RESULT_CONST_COL
 USING TEMP2_VAR_TEST.TABLE_NAME;
```

Then iterate through returned results in collection to process all values:

```
FOR i IN 1 .. RESULT_CONST_COL.COUNT LOOP
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RESULT_CONST_COL(i));
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '|| TEMP2_VAR_TEST ||
  ' DISABLE CONSTRAINT ' || RESULT_CONST_COL(i);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: hi yaroslav thanks for helping out... encountered errors when i tried to follow your suggestion. expression RESULT_CONST_COL is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement... another error component COUNT must be declared. I am attempting to fix this right now.

Comment: @dimas To assign value to collection element you have to use index: `RESULT_CONST_COL(1) := 'some_value'`. There can be any number in place of `1` that is less or equal than total number of elements in collection. Regarding `COUNT` could you post the line of code where this error is raised?

Comment: hi yaroslav i've manage to get rid of errors show regarding result_const_col but its coming up with another error. Please see update 1

Comment: @dimas Sorry for mistake in the code. You have to use just `BULK COLLECT INTO`. That's true `RETURNING` is needed if you dynamically execute `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: That's fine yaroslav, fix you made is brillian. Procedure is now working. Just a follow up question on this because the result will give me rows of foreign keys per table. Can I use RESULT_CONST_COL to iterate through each row and disabe foreign keys using ALTER statemen?

Comment: Sure you can. Just added an example to my answer. Perhaps you have to add some logic to check if the constraint if foreign key or not.

Comment: Thanks alot Yaroslav, you really helped me alot.